# SQL select max duplicate value as the main group

Tags: sql

I have a tale of SiteID which is not correct because 1 SiteID have more than 1 Group
Noted!!! One Group can have more than one Site ID

```
SiteID   | AccountID | Group
--------------------------
6480021A | 64800211  | A01
6480021A | 64800212  | A01
6480021A | 64800213  | A01
6480021A | 64800214  | A01
6480021A | 64800215  | A02
6480021A | 64800216  | A02
6480021A | 64800217  | NULL
```

Then I count how many groups are there in each SiteID as below;

```
SiteID   | Group | Count
--------------------------
6480021A | A01   | 4
6480021A | A02   | 2
6480021A | NULL  | 1
```

Then I will select Group which has max Count as the main group.
So it should select A01 as the main Group as below table;

```
SiteID   | AccountID | Group
--------------------------
6480021A | 64800211  | A01
6480021A | 64800212  | A01
6480021A | 64800213  | A01
6480021A | 64800214  | A01
6480021A | 64800215  | A01
6480021A | 64800216  | A01
6480021A | 64800217  | A01
```

Right now I'm stuck in the last process which is select max Count as the main group.
This is my query;

```
    ----Count SITE_ID that has more than 1 Group----
SELECT DISTINCT s.[SITE_ID]
INTO Table CountSite
FROM (SELECT Distinct s.[SITE_ID]
            ,case when s.[GROUP] is null then 'NULL' else s.[GROUP] end as [GROUP]
      FROM  Table SiteID s)   
GROUP BY s.[SITE_ID]            
HAVING count(s.[GROUP]) > 1


----Count GROUP in each SITE_ID-----
SELECT c.[SITE_ID]
      ,e.[GROUP]
      ,e.[COUNT_GROUP]
INTO #tmp2
FROM Table CountSite c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [SITE_ID]
                 ,[GROUP]
                 ,count([GROUP]) as 'COUNT_GROUP'
            FROM Table SiteID
            GROUP BY [SITE_ID],[GROUP]) e on c.[SITE_ID] = e.[SITE_ID]


----Select max count GROUP as main GROUP for each SITE_ID'
```

I still don't have idea for this one.